# How to get the arch string that distutils uses for builds?

Tags: python, distutils, python-c-extension

When I build a c extension using `python setup.py build`, the result is created under a directory named

```
build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/
```

where the part after `lib.` changes by the OS, CPU and Python version.

Is there a way I can access the appropriate string for my current architecture from python? Hopefully in a way that is guaranteed to match what distutils is creating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> from distutils import util
>>> util.get_platform()
'linux-x86_64'

>>> import sys
>>> '%s.%s' % sys.version_info[:2]
2.6
```